# Error with adding text components in psychopy procedure

Tags: text, error-handling, psychopy

I have downloaded the procedure I have on my laptop on my lab’s computer from my Google Drive, and I had to take some edits to test it.In order to this, I have to add some text components with some specific code. However when I tried to add and use the $ symbol to read the text I would like to refer to, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/psychopy/app/builder/dialogs/paramCtrls.py", line 31, in validate
    validate(self, self.valType)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/psychopy/app/builder/dialogs/paramCtrls.py", line 550, in validate
    val = str(obj.GetValue())
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Could anyone possibly have some good piece of advice or workaround to manage with it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What version of PsychoPy are you using? I believe this was fixed in Feb 2022 so probably updating to a new version of psychopy should fix it for you.
https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy/pull/4569

Comment: Thanks. I am using v2022.2.4. Could you please tell me which files exactly I have to download?